# POSTing a nested NSDictionary using AFNetworking 2

Tags: ios, http, post, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

Using the Postman extension for Chrome I can successfully POST some JSON. Using Charles to inspect the request, I see that the request data is as follows:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "user_id": "12345"
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to construct this same request using AFNetworking 2.4.1, I can see that the data is formatted as:

```
query[term][user_id]=12345
```

The server of course returns an error.

What part of the POST request am I getting wrong?

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"query":@{@"term":@{@"user_id":@"12345"}}};

[manager POST:@"http://someURL" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"SUCCESS %@", responseObject);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"FAIL: %@", error);
    }];
```

Comment: Got answer ? please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is:

```
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
```

From the documentation:

> Requests created with `requestWithMethod:URLString:parameters:` &
>   `multipartFormRequestWithMethod:URLString:parameters:constructingBodyWithBlock:`
>   are constructed with a set of default headers using a parameter
>   serialization specified by this property. By default, this is set to
>   an instance of `AFHTTPRequestSerializer`, which serializes query
>   string parameters for `GET`, `HEAD`, and `DELETE` requests, or
>   otherwise URL-form-encodes HTTP message bodies.